# OpenCV how do conversions of Matrix elements work

Tags: opencv

I am having trouble understanding the inner workings of OpenCV. Consider the following code:

```
Scalar getAverageColor(Mat img, vector<Rect>& rois) {

    int n = static_cast<int>(rois.size());
    Mat avgs(1, n, CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        // What is the correct way to assign the color elements in 
        // the matrix?
        avgs.at<Scalar>(i) = mean(Mat(img, rois[i]));
        /*
        This seems to always work, but there has to be a better way.
        avgs.at<Vec3b>(i)[0] = mean(Mat(img, rois[i]))[0];
        avgs.at<Vec3b>(i)[1] = mean(Mat(img, rois[i]))[1];
        avgs.at<Vec3b>(i)[2] = mean(Mat(img, rois[i]))[2];
        */
    }
    // If I access the first element it seems to be set correctly.
    Scalar first = avgs.at<Scalar>(0);
    // However mean returns [0 0 0 0] if I did the assignment above using scalar, why???
    Scalar avg = mean(avgs);
    return avg;
}
```

If I use `avgs.at<Scalar>(i) = mean(Mat(img, rois[i]))` for the assignment in the loop the first element looks correct, but then the mean calculation always returns zero (even thought the first element looks correct). If I assign all the color elements by hand using Vec3b it seems to work, but why???

Comment: `avgs.at<Scalar>(i)` and `avgs` is `CV_8UC3` -- you're reinterpreting a structure with 3 bytes as a structure with 4 doubles.

Comment: (at<T> is basically a reinterpret_cast on the data pointer), so the first element in `avgs` are basically the 3 MSBs from the 8-byte mean of the first channel (and the rest spills to following elements, or overflows the buffer near the end).

Comment: Outch! Write that as an answer and I will happily accept it!

Comment: However `avgs.at<Vec4b>(i) = Vec4b(mean(Mat(img, rois[i])));` works too. What would be the proper way to assign a Scalar (as returned by mean(...)) to a CV_8UC3 Mat?

Comment: That's a bit trickier, see the answer. There is a cast from `Scalar` to 4-element `cv::Vec` of any type, but again using `Vec4b` on a 3 channel mat will cause havoc (this is more for other readers, as your earlier comment suggests that you  understand how bad that is).

Comment: Now that I look at the actual function, maybe you'd be better off to make `avgs` a `CV_64FC3` (keep the means as doubles, no rounding/flooring at that stage) and only convert the final mean of all the ROI averages. Less chance for accumulating rounding errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** [`cv::Scalar`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga599fe92e910c027be274233eccad7beb) is a typedef for [`cv::Scalar_<double>`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/da0/classcv_1_1Scalar__.html), which derives from [`cv::Vec<double, 4>`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/dcf/classcv_1_1Vec.html), which derives from [`cv::Matx<double, 4, 1>`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/de1/classcv_1_1Matx.html).
Similarly, [`cv::Vec3b`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga7e6060c0b8d48459964df6e1eb524c03) is `cv::Vec<uint8_t, 3>` which derives from `cv::Matx<uint8_t, 3, 1>` -- this means that we can use any of those 3 in `cv::Mat::at` and get identical (correct) behaviour.

---

It's important to be aware that [`cv::Mat::at`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5d20fc86d41d59e4d71ae93daee9726) is [basically a `reinterpret_cast`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/ef5579dc8667e5eb5e149acc4af898421eed99da/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L1157) on the underlying data array. You need to be extremely careful to use an appropriate data type for the template argument, one which corresponds to the type of elements (including channel count) of the `cv::Mat` you're invoking it on.

The documentation mentions the following:

> Keep in mind that the size identifier used in the at operator cannot be chosen at random. It depends on the image from which you are trying to retrieve the data. The table below gives a better insight in this:
>
> - If matrix is of type `CV_8U` then use `Mat.at<uchar>(y,x)`.
> - If matrix is of type `CV_8S` then use `Mat.at<schar>(y,x)`.
> - If matrix is of type `CV_16U` then use `Mat.at<ushort>(y,x)`.
> - If matrix is of type `CV_16S` then use `Mat.at<short>(y,x)`.
> - If matrix is of type `CV_32S` then use `Mat.at<int>(y,x)`.
> - If matrix is of type `CV_32F` then use `Mat.at<float>(y,x)`.
> - If matrix is of type `CV_64F` then use `Mat.at<double>(y,x)`.

It doesn't seem to mention there what to do in case of multiple channels -- in that case you use `cv::Vec<...>` (or rather one of the typedefs provided). `cv::Vec<...>` is basically a wrapper around an fixed-size array of N values of given type.

---

In your case, the matrix `avgs` is `CV_8UC3` -- each element consists of 3 unsigned byte values (i.e. 3 bytes total). However, by using `avgs.at<Scalar>(i)`, you interpret each element as 4 doubles (32 bytes in total). That means that:

- The actual element you tried to write to (if interpreted correctly) will only hold the 3 most significant bytes of the (8 byte floating point) mean of the first channel -- i.e. complete garbage.
- You actually overwrite the next 10 elements (the last one partially, 3rd channel escapes unscathed) with more garbage.
- At some point, you are bound to overflow the buffer and potentially trash other data structures. This issue is rather serious.

We can demonstrate it using the following simple program.

**Example:**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat test_mat(cv::Mat::zeros(1, 12, CV_8UC3)); // 12 * 3 = 36 bytes of data
    std::cout << "Before: " << test_mat << "\n";

    cv::Scalar test_scalar(cv::Scalar::all(1234.5678));    
    test_mat.at<cv::Scalar>(0, 0) = test_scalar;
    std::cout << "After: " << test_mat << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before: [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]
After: [173, 250,  92, 109,  69,  74, 147,  64, 173, 250,  92, 109,  69,  74, 147,  64, 173, 250,  92, 109,  69,  74, 147,  64, 173, 250,  92, 109,  69,  74, 147,  64,   0,   0,   0,   0]
```

This clearly shows we're writing way more than we should.

In Debug mode, the incorrect use of `at` also triggers an assertion:

```
OpenCV(3.4.3) Error: Assertion failed (((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((traits::Depth<_Tp>::value) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file D:\code\shit\so07\deps\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 1102
```

---

To allow assignment of the result from `cv::mean` (which is a `cv::Scalar`) to our `CV_8UC3` matrix, we need to do two things (not necessarily in this order):

- Convert the values from `double` to `uint8_t` -- OpenCV will do a [`saturate_cast`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gab93126370b85fda2c8bfaf8c811faeaf), but given that the mean won't go past the min/max of the input items, we'd be fine with a regular cast.
- Get rid of the 4th element.

To remove the 4th element, we can use [`cv::Matx::get_minor`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/de1/classcv_1_1Matx.html#a3e180104b35cf9a24d129619ba18aba7) (The documentation is a bit lacking, but a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/7442100caaa9e6dafce320aeb0afcf86e8aea11c/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp#L745) explains it fairly well). The result is a `cv::Matx`, so we have to use that instead of `cv::Vec` when using `cv::Mat::at`.

The two possible options then are:

- Get rid of the 4th element and then 
  [cast](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/de1/classcv_1_1Matx.html#a52462c5d76a61e63881055bc96fcc711) result to convert the `cv::Matx` to `uint8_t` element type.
- [Cast](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/da0/classcv_1_1Scalar__.html#a80e2d82a29fc3de327c8c30343129d7c) the `cv::Scalar` to `cv::Scalar_<uint8_t>` first, and then get rid of the 4th element.

**Example:**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

typedef cv::Matx<uint8_t, 3, 1> Mat31b; // Convenience, OpenCV only has typedefs for double and float variants

int main()
{
    cv::Mat test_mat(1, 12, CV_8UC3); // 12 * 3 = 36 bytes of data
    test_mat = cv::Scalar(1, 1, 1); // Set all elements to 1
    std::cout << "Before: " << test_mat << "\n";

    cv::Scalar test_scalar{ 2,3,4,0 };
    cv::Matx31d temp = test_scalar.get_minor<3, 1>(0, 0);
    test_mat.at<Mat31b>(0, 0) = static_cast<Mat31b>(temp);

    // or
    // cv::Scalar_<uint8_t> temp(static_cast<cv::Scalar_<uint8_t>>(test_scalar));
    // test_mat.at<Mat31b>(0, 0) = temp.get_minor<3, 1>(0, 0);


    std::cout << "After: " << test_mat << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

*NB: You can get rid of the explicit temporaries, they're here just for easier readability.*

**Output:**

Both options produce the following output:

```
Before: [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1]
After: [  2,   3,   4,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1]
```

As we can see, only the first 3 bytes were changed, so it behaves correctly.

---

*Some thoughts about performance.*

It's hard to guess which of the two approaches is better. Casting first means you allocate smaller amount of memory for the temporary, but then you have to do 4 `saturate_cast`s instead of 3. Some benchmarking would have to be done (excercise for the reader). The calculation of mean will outweigh it significantly, so it's likely to be irrelevant.

Given that we don't really need the `saturate_cast`s, perhaps the simple, but more verbose approach (optimized version of the thing that worked for you) might perform better in a tight loop.

```
cv::Vec3b& current_element(avgs.at<cv::Vec3b>(i));
cv::Scalar current_mean(cv::mean(cv::Mat(img, rois[i])));
for (int n(0); n < 3; ++n) {
    current_element[n] = static_cast<uint8_t>(current_mean[n]);
}
```

---

**Update:**

One more idea that came up in discussion with [@alkasm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5087436/alkasm). The assignment operator for a `cv::Mat` is vectorized when given a `cv::Scalar` (it assigns the same value to all elements), and it ignores the additional channel values the `cv::Scalar` may hold relative to the target `cv::Mat` type. (e.g. for a 3-channel `Mat` it ignores the 4th value).

We could take a 1x1 ROI of the target `Mat`, and assign it the mean `Scalar`. Necessary type conversions will happen, and the 4th channel will be discared. Probably not optimal, but it's by far the least amount of code so far.

```
test_mat(cv::Rect(0, 0, 1, 1)) = test_scalar;
```

The result is the same as before.

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to know how to write short answers :D

Comment: What does the b stand for in cv::Vec3b? unsigned char?

Comment: Thank you for such an elaborate answer!

Comment: @Nils Yeah, b means unsigned char.

Comment: Guess it stands for byte the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: @Nils Yep, and the rest are **s**hort (signed 16bit), **w**ord (unsigned 16bit), **i**nt (signed 32bit), **f**loat and **d**ouble. Those are the 6 types that `cv::Mat` supports.

Comment: Sorry, 6 out of 7 types. For some reason there's no shortcut/typedefs for signed characters.